# Python str.format() list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, format

I am trying to develop a format that prints a certain way when iterating through a list of dictionaries.

Error Raised: "tuple index out of range"

I have looked at several other questions that with a similar topic and know that you can't key in using a numerical value and format(). At least that's what I got from it.

In my case I am not using a numerical value so not sure why it isn't working. I think I know how to solve this using the other (%S) formatting method but trying to condense and make my code more pythonic.

So when I remove the .formate statement and leave the indexing arguments I get the correct values, but as soon as I try to format them I get the error.

My code:

```
def namelist(names):
    n = len(names)
    return_format = {
    0: '{}',
    1: '{} & {}',
    2:'{}, {} & {}'
    }
    name_stucture = return_format[n-1]
    for idx, element in enumerate(names):
        print name_stucture.format(names[idx]["name"])
```

Looking for why this is happening and how to resolve it, thanks!

Comment: Sample structur of `names` which you are passing?

Comment: Sorry! namelist([ {'name': 'George'}, {'name': 'Alfred'}, {'name': 'Abe'}])

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems simpler than you're trying to make it:

```
formats = [None, '{}', '{} & {}']

def namelist(names):
    length = len(names)

    if length > 2:
        name_format = '{}, ' * (length - 2) + formats[2]  # handle any number of names
    else:
        name_format = formats[length]

    print(name_format.format(*names))

namelist(['Tom'])
namelist(['Tom', 'Dick'])
namelist(['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'])
namelist(['Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo', 'Zeppo'])

# the data structure is messy so clean it up rather than dirty the function:
namelist([d['name'] for d in [{'name': 'George'}, {'name': 'Alfred'}, {'name': 'Abe'}]])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Tom
Tom & Dick
Tom, Dick & Harry
Groucho, Chico, Harpo & Zeppo
George, Alfred & Abe
>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting occurs when you try to unpack a format string with too few arguments. Here is a basic example:

```
>>> '{}{}'.format('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

This occurs even if you pass a list as one argument. You need to *unpack* the list with the asterisk:

Without unpacking:

```
>>> x = ['one', 'two']
>>> '{}{}'.format(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

With unpacking:

```
>>> x = ['one', 'two']
>>> '{}{}'.format(*x)
'onetwo'
```

### Edit

There are some other issues as well: you are looping through each name and printing the specified format, but there is no need for looping at all unless you want to print the names three times each. The use of `names[idx]`, instead of just `element` is also unnecessary and unpythonic.

Preserving some of your patterns, here is a working example:

```
names = [ {'name': 'George'}, {'name': 'Alfred'}, {'name': 'Abe'}]

def namelist(names):
  name_structure = ['{}', '{} & {}', '{}, {}, & {}'][min(2, len(names) - 1)]
  name_structure.format(*[name['name'] for name in names])
```

Note that this function will have unexpected behavior if you have more than three names: it will only print the first three names.

Comment: Okay so that allows you to unpack the list and returns the dictionaries that were contained in it. Is it then possible to key into those dictionaries to just return the values in that format, or no?

Comment: @eeskonivich Yes, you can key into the dictionary, like I did in my example using a list comprehension. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that when working through it. I didn't see your posting before I commented. Thank you for the help, but I do have one more question on [max(2, len(names)-1)] , what are you doing here? It is being used in a context I haven't seen. The values you passed in are integers and not an iterable. I understand everything else. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The reason I added that is because if you pass a list with more than 3 elements, you will get an `IndexError`. `max` ensures that the value will not be greater than 2, so that if you pass a list with five values, it will use the third format. Make sense?

Comment: So it defaults to the 3 element format if there are more than 3? It looks like you are indexing into the list of formats that you created, is that right? And if the index doesn't exist the error is raised.

Comment: Oops, now I feel stupid: that should have been `min` :) I changed it now. The point is that if len(names) == 5, for instance, then it will choose the highest possible value, which in this case is 2.

Comment: Okay great! Thanks you so much for your help